# How to set Firefox path on Mac OS for Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am beginner to webdriver. I have setup all configurations. I am using firefox 27.0.1 version with selenium jar files 2.40.0. I have written code to open firefox browser with a URL. I am unable to run the code and got the below error. Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be Mac. It seems i should specify the firefox path to run the code. I tried to find the location on my mac. All i get is /Users/sathiyarengarajan/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles. Tell me how to get the exact path on mac machine.

Answer (score 3):

The typical location of FF is `/Users/username/Applications/Firefox`

To confirm the location right click on an FF shortcut and select `"Get info"`.  The dialog box displays.

Comment: I tried using Get info. Still I am only able to get the same above. I tried even Firefox help->troubleshoot information->Application Basics->Profile folder->show it in Finder. Any help to get the exact location would be helpful

Comment: Why don't you just search the HD for Firefox? Use the search in Finder.

Comment: I tried. I got /Users/sathiyarengarajan/Downloads/Firefox 27.0.1.dmg. But still it didnt help. I uninstalled the firefox application. Once firefox is downloaded, i copied the firefox to the applications folder. Now I no need to set firefox path for selenium. Now things work

Comment: No you should be good now, the applications folder is Selemiums default location for Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same problem, but since I found this answer when googling, I'm providing my solution here too.

I'm trying to find the firefox executable to execute it from scripts like cucumber / selenium tests without hardcoding the path. Here's what I do:

Find it with  Spotlight

```
firefox_paths = %x[mdfind "kMDItemFSName = Firefox.app"]
firefox_path = firefox_paths.split('\n').first.chomp
firefox_executable_path = File.join(firefox_path, '/Contents/MacOS/firefox')

Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=firefox_executable_path
```

Another way would be to dump launch services database and grep it out there

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump \
  | grep -n7 org.mozilla.firefox \
  | grep path: \
  | awk '{ print($3) }'
```

Answer (score 2):

I put the `geckodriver` to `/usr/local/bin/` directory, when I start selenium test, the log show default search path on Mac OS

```
geckodriver::marionette INFO     Starting browser /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

So make sure you have `firefox-bin` in above path, if not, you can make a soft link to your search path, for example:

```
ln -s /Applications/FirefoxDeveloperEdition.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin /usr/local/bin/firefox-bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me share a crude but fool-proof way to find this:
On Terminal, type `find /Applications -name *Firefox*`

This will give you all paths to any file with firefox in the name. You should see these two lines in the output:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

Hope this will helps.

---

Alternatively from the UI :

> Go to Finder, under locate Firefox Applications
>   Right click and Open Package Contents. You will see MacOS folder. 
>   Drill down each subfolders. You will find that the executables you will see will be under MacOS, named firefox and firefox-bin.

Hope this also helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I had multiple versions of FireFox browsers.

Got the error below:

> Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: MAC

I Uninstalled the older version and the test started passing.

```
    package com.chamlabs.restfulservices.client.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.safari.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Driver;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LogInPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("google.com");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.close();

    }
}
```